# Connecting Orange to Sql Server

Tags: orange

I've installed Orange 3.34.0 and I'd like to connect "Sql Table" object to my Sql Server 2008 "R2".
I've installed Python 3.11 and launched the command "pip install pymssql" succesfuly.
Once finished, I restarted Orange and tryed to configure "Sql Table" with no result.
The "Sql Tabel" object interface looks like blocked (I cannot insert any configuration parameter) furthermore, in the bottom of the above mentioned interfece error reporting "Please install a backend to use this widget", appears.
The workaround has went ahead trying with the python command "pip install sqlalchemy" and once again this attempt has been completed successfully.
Unfortunately when Orange restarted, the same result occurred (no chance to set parameters and same message about the "backend to be installed" was shown.

Then I tried to install the 3.9 version of Python that seems to be the one used by Orange.
Installation succeeded bun "Sql Table" object still blocked and with the same error message.
(Yes I restarted the PC too).

Any suggestion?